# how to get elements values from simple xml

Tags: php, xml

I have the following xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<root> 
<offers count="3009">
<offer>
    <offerId>25</offerId>
    <offer_type>for sale</offer_type>
    <offer_status>available</offer_status>
     <building_floors></building_floors>
    <title>title</title> 
<photos count="4">
<photo zIndex="1">1.jpg</photo>
<photo zIndex="2">2.jpg</photo>
<photo zIndex="3">3.jpg</photo>
<photo zIndex="4">4.jpg</photo>
     </photos>
  </offer>
</offers>
</root>
```

I am using this php code to get results from the xml:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("offers.xml") 
       or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->children() as $offers){
    foreach($offers->children() as $offer => $data){
    echo $data->offerId;echo "<br />";//and so on for each element
          foreach ($xml->offers->offer->photos->photo as $aaa){
         $photos=$aaa; echo "<br />";
         //echo $xml;
         $photo = explode("<br /> ", $photos);
            foreach($photo as $value) echo $value; echo '<br />';//echo $value
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to loop the photo element I get all photos but only for the first offer. 
My question is what I am doing wrong and why I do not get photos for each offer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way you retrieve the photo elements. You start from the root element so it always give you the same  node.
You should use $data like this :

```
foreach ($data->photos->photo as $aaa){
```

cleaning a bit your code you should use this to display the photo elements:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("offers.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->children() as $offers){
    foreach($offers->children() as $offer){
        echo "Offer id : " . $offer->offerId . "<br>";
        foreach ($offer->photos->photo as $photo){
            $val = (string) $photo;
            echo $val . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```